# How to verify Audio data is valid?

Tags: macos, audio, avfoundation, core-audio, avcapturesession

I'm trying to capture audio of the microphone using `AVCaptureSession` with below setup,

```
AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];

AVCaptureDevice* audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSError* error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput* audioInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"AVCaptureDeviceInput Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

if ([captureSession canAddInput:audioInput]) {
    [captureSession addInput:audioInput];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to add Audio Input to Capture Session");
}

AVCaptureAudioDataOutput* audioOutput = [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput new];

NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey, nil];
audioOutput.audioSettings = settings;

dispatch_queue_t audioQueue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioSessionQueue", nil);
[audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:audioQueue];

if ([captureSession canAddOutput:audioOutput]) {
    [captureSession addOutput:audioOutput];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to add Audio Output to Capture Session");
}

[captureSession commitConfiguration];
[captureSession startRunning];

currentSession = captureSession;
```

I get some data in the `-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` delegate method and I convert it to NSData as below,

```
AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);
CMItemCount numSamples = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer);
NSUInteger size = sizeof(audioBufferList);
char buffer[size];
((int*)buffer)[0] = (int)numSamples;
memcpy(buffer, &audioBufferList, size);
//This is the Audio data.
NSData *bufferData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:size];
```

Now my question is how to verify that the data is a valid audio?

Comment: Just cut an output file ... Or fill an array then examine it's contents ... Or print to log and compare to known input audio ... On your laptop play a sin wave of known values say with known min and max values ... For simplicity only do mono until it's working

Comment: @ScottStensland im new to Mac development and audio processing. Also the input audio is coming from microphone, so I guess its not a known input audio. How can I cut an output file? Can you provide any example? Since Im capturing linear PCM format I couldn't directly write it in file and play it. when I added wave header to the data, audio file just played a beep in spite of 10 seconds captured data.

Comment: becoming a productive software engineer means attaining independence from having to ask questions and waiting for answers ... invest more time thinking about what you need and peeling it apart into discoverable achievable solutions ... all of us who have a specialty in audio or any similar low level interest must gain this freedom and independence - good luck